# An almost upper bound. Is this a counter example? (SPIVAK)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I got this exercise from Spivak's book. I am having problems interpreting the answers and the question.

[image]

The first problem is

$\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The answer says all $\alpha >0$ and $\alpha \leq 0$ are the almost upper bound and almost lower bound.

But there is a problem, suppose $\alpha = 5$ is my almost upper bound, then this contradicts the definition they have because clearly no number in the set is bigger or even equal to $5$. I am assuming they are using $\alpha$ for $x$

**EDIT**

Still something wrong. For $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, the almost upper bound is $\alpha > 0$ and $\alpha < 0$ for almost lower bound. But isn't technically every number an upper/lower bound? How do we know there are finitely many numbers in the set such that $\alpha > 0$ is an upper bound?

Comment: With your example of 5 there are no elements in the set that are larger or equal to 5. Hence finitely many from the set are above or equal to 5. 0 is a finite number.

Comment: I think that in this context, zero numbers is finitely many numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\alpha=5$, then there are $0$ numbers $y$ in $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $y\ge \alpha$. Since $0$ is finite, $\alpha$ is an almost upper bound for $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb N\}$.

More succinctly, $0$ is a finite number.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\alpha>0$. You want to show that $\alpha$ is an almost upper bound for the set $\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. In other words, you want to show that only finitely many elements of the set $\{1/n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is larger than or equal to $\alpha$.

If $\alpha>1$, this is quite easy, because there are 0 such numbers as Alex notes.

If $\alpha \le 1$, let $N$ be a sufficiently large positive integer such that $\alpha>\frac{1}{N}$. Can you proceed from here?

**Edit:** Sorry, I realize that you were only asking about the case $\alpha=5$. Well, I will keep my answer, as it provides hint to the solution of the problem :)

Comment: Coudl you look at my updated question?